# Android options menu closed every time screen orientation changes

Tags: android, contextmenu, orientation

For some reason, every time the screen orientation is changed my app closes the context menu if it was open. All applications I have seen keep menus open after rotating the screen, but I cannot figure out why my app is closing them.

I am not handling configuration changes on my own and my onCreate method, which I know is called after every orientation change, does not touch menus at all. I would appreciate any insights on this problem.

Comment: I'm not adding this as an answer, because I'm an unsure if I am correct... but I believe you will have to handle this state and store it in an overridden onSaveInstanceState() call.

Comment: I solved it! I was just forgetting to call super.onSaveInstanceState() from within my own onSaveInstanceState() method, so the default state information that is usually saved was not being saved.

Answer (score 1):

The contextMenu disappeared because by default when rotating android calls destroy() and then onCreate() but :

If you don't want Android to go through the normal activity destroy-and-recreate process; instead, you want to handle recreating the views yourself, you can use the android:configChanges attributes on the element in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
</activity>
```

This way contextMenu is not closed when phone rotates, because onCreate() method is not called.

This topic can also be helpful - [Activity restart on rotation Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android)

Comment: I understand the destroy-and-recreate process. What I don't understand is how I am interrupting the default behavior. I created a simple activity with only the following code:
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
When I run this and flip the orientation, the menu remains open.